# Add Timestamp to file JAVA

Tags: java, printing, timestamp, filenames

In the console, in eclipse, The current timestamp pops up, and I can type next to it whatever I'd like to be put into the file.

How do I get that timestamp to print in the file as well!?!?

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.util.Date;
    public class bufferedwriter {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lineToPrint = "";
        String fileName = "/Users/josephbosco/fileName.txt";

        do{
            java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
            System.out.print(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));

             lineToPrint = myScanner.nextLine();                 
            printToFile (fileName, lineToPrint);                

        } while (!lineToPrint.equalsIgnoreCase("q") );          

    }

    public static void printToFile (String myfileName, String message) {        

        try {
            File outfile = new File(myfileName);

            //if file doesn't exist, then create it

            if (!outfile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("No file exists...writing a new file");
                outfile.createNewFile();

            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outfile.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(message);

            bw.flush(); 
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is currently instantiating a new Timestamp object within the print statement. The problem is you are not storing that Timestamp to a variable so that it can be referenced again when attempting to write it to the file.

```
do{
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    System.out.print(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));


    lineToPrint = myScanner.nextLine();

    printToFile (fileName, lineToPrint);


} while (!lineToPrint.equalsIgnoreCase("q") );
```

Storing the Timestamp object to a variable allows you to reference the variable within a print statement; this also makes concatenation of the timestamp variable and lineToPrint variable easier to code. The revised code below shows these changes.

```
do{
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();

    // Initialize variable and store new Timestamp object
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime()));

    System.out.print(timestamp)
    lineToPrint = myScanner.nextLine();

    // Concatenate the two variables
    printToFile (fileName, timestamp + " " + lineToPrint);


} while (!lineToPrint.equalsIgnoreCase("q") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `bw.write(message);` simply add the following:

```
bw.write(new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()).toString());
```

Comment: when i tried that i had an error under "write" saying    - The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (Timestamp)

Comment: Try using `bw.write(new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()).toString());`